# How to get the Items between two certain Symbols in a List

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I made a Example List looking like this:

```
dataList = ["tv", "•", "tv", "tv", "•", "tv", "•", "tv", "tv", "•"]
```

I want to print out the Items that are enclosed by `•`.

In this example,

```
tv, tv
tv
tv, tv
```

I came up with the following code:

```
num = 0
num2 = 0
index = 0
boolean = True

for index, elem in enumerate(dataList2):
    boolean = True
    num = index + 1,
    num = int(num[0])
    if elem == "•":
        counter = 0
        if boolean:
            boolean = False
            for elem2 in dataList2[num:]:
                counter = counter + 1,
                counter = int(counter[0])
                if elem2 == "•":
                    print("\n")
                    num2 = counter + num,
                    num2 = int(num2[0])
                    for el in dataList2[num:num2]:
                        print(el, end=" ")
```

I get this output:

```
tv tv • 

tv tv • tv • 

tv tv • tv • tv tv • 

tv • 

tv • tv tv • 

tv tv •
```

As you can see I get the unwanted behaviour that

```
tv tv • tv •

tv tv • tv • tv tv •

tv • tv tv •
```

are included in the output. I tried to fix the behaviour with a boolean but that didnt work out. What did I do wrong?

Comment: your approach can be a bit simpler if you use while loops.

Comment: ah got it, didnt get the idea to do that, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach would be to find the indices of the special character, and split the list into chunks between the first and last occurrence:

```
indices = [i for i, v in enumerate(dataList) if v == "•"]
result = [dataList[indices[i - 1] + 1:indices[i]] for i in range(1, len(indices))]
```

For your input, you get

```
>>> result
[['tv', 'tv'], ['tv'], ['tv', 'tv']]
```

Now you can print and do other things with that value. For example:

```
>>> for s in result:
...     print(*s, sep=', ')
tv, tv
tv
tv, tv
```

It's always better to compute intermediate results than just print them if you plan to reuse them for something else.

Comment: Perhaps `[dataList[i+1:j] for i,j in zip(indices, indices[1:])]`, but that's a personal style choice.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny. I'm glad you noted it in the comments. I generally find my way to be preferable because the index is more explicit, and it somehow grinds my gears to allocate an extra list for `indixes[1:]`. I'll be the first to admit that your suggestion looks prettier though, so I'm glad you posted it as an alternative.

Comment: There's one more way though, starting from python 3.10 there's [`itertools.pairwise()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) and if we'll turn `indexes` into a generator and call `next()` once, it should be a good alternative with `O(n)` complexity *(I haven't check C implementation, so can't be sure in last statement, but it seems to be legit)*.

Comment: @OlvinRoght. You could always `itertools.tee` it from the very beginning.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, but `pairwise()` is implemented on C level and in fact it's an iterator with buffer for previous element. [Sources](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f4c03484da59049eb62a9bf7777b963e2267d187/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L54).

Comment: @OlvinRoght. Oh, I understand that it's much more efficient. I'm just suggesting that there were probably at least a half dozen options available even before `pairwise`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, sure, the reason why I decided to mention `pairwise()` is that it's quite new tool which soon will become a standard.

Answer (score 1):

```py
dataList = ["tv", "•", "tv", "tv", "•", "tv", "•", "tv", "tv", "•"]
searchFor = "•"
allVals = []
isFound = False
oldIdx = -1
for idx, item in enumerate(dataList):
    if item == searchFor:
        if isFound:
            # loop complete
            allVals.append(dataList[oldIdx + 1 : idx ])
            isFound = False
        else:
            isFound = True
            oldIdx = idx
```

```py
allVals
[['tv', 'tv'], ['tv', 'tv']]
```

```py
allStrings = [",".join(x) for x in allVals]

allStrings
['tv,tv', 'tv,tv']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below

```
data = ["tv", "•", "tv", "tv", "•", "tv", "•", "tv", "tv", "•"]
temp = []
counter = 0
for d in data:
  if d == "•":
    if counter == 1:
      print(','.join(temp))
      temp = []
      counter = 1
    else:
      counter += 1
  else:
    if counter != 0:
      temp.append(d)
if temp:
  print(','.join(temp))
```

output

```
tv,tv
tv
tv,tv
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a slightly shorter version of the iterative solutions

```
dataList = ["tv", "•", "tv", "tv", "•", "tv", "•", "tv", "tv", "•"]

sub = ['tv']
for i in dataList:
    if i == '•':
        if sub[0] == '•':
            print(*sub[1:], sep=', ')
        sub = []
    sub += [i]
```

Output

```
tv, tv
tv
tv, tv
```